# C# Graphics DrawImage function Re-scales bitmap extracted from an original bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmapimage, drawimage, img-area-select-jquery

I have been trying to get the section of an image by giving the coordinates of the image. Here is the code that extracts image from the original image.

```
     private byte[] ExtractImageSection(Bitmap originalMap, ImagePart imgPart)
     {
        Bitmap imageSection = new Bitmap(imgPart.Width, imgPart.Height);

        int top = Math.Min(imgPart.Y1, imgPart.Y2);
        int bottom = Math.Max(imgPart.Y1, imgPart.Y2);
        int left = Math.Min(imgPart.X1, imgPart.X2);
        int right = Math.Max(imgPart.X1, imgPart.X2);

        Rectangle cloneRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageSection);

        // Draw the given area (section) of the source image
        // at location 0,0 on the empty bitmap (imageSection)
        //g.DrawImage(originalMap, 0, 0, cloneRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        g.DrawImage(originalMap, cloneRect, 0, 0, imgPart.Width, imgPart.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        /* Code Commented - Clone Bitmap method
        int top = Math.Min(imgPart.Y1, imgPart.Y2);
        int bottom = Math.Max(imgPart.Y1, imgPart.Y2);
        int left = Math.Min(imgPart.X1, imgPart.X2);
        int right = Math.Max(imgPart.X1, imgPart.X2);

        Rectangle cloneRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat = originalMap.PixelFormat;
        Bitmap imageSection = (Bitmap)originalMap.Clone(cloneRect, pixelFormat);*/

        imageSection.Save(pageImageLocation + imgPart.ImagePartName, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imageSectionByte = ConvertBitmapIntoByte(imageSection);
        return imageSectionByte;
    }
```

The commented code represents the ways that I've used so far to achieve my goal. I used the following stack-overflow link to try to fix the issue but I still did not work. Here is the original image (`originalMap`)

[image: originalMap]

Above function tries to get the highlighted section. The function gets `X1, Y1, X2, Y2, Width, Heigth` from front end. To get the required values I am using 
[imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)

Things I have done so far to figure out the issue

1. I have also debugged the code to verify the coordinates, width, and
   height of the extracted part. (they were correct)
2. Tried variants of `DrawImage` from `Graphics` class.
3. Tried `Clone` method of `Bitmap` to clone the original image based on the section coordinates as you can see the commented code.

Here is the image after the extract method.

[image: After Extract]

Can anyone please help me figure out this workaround of the issue?